# What is the most efficient manner to handle errors in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, assertion, isinstance

I'm newbie in python and I'm trying to handle errors but I don't know the most efficient way to handle errors in python. I tried this way, but it seems a bit complex to understand. I think may can exist some other "better" manner to handle it.

```
def set_bit(value, pos, nbits):
"""
Set bit at position.

Keyword Arguments
    value (int)
        Bitstring value.
    pos (int)
        Position to set bit.
    nbits (int)
        Number of bits.
"""
if isinstance(value, int):
    if value > -1:
        # Positives only
        if isinstance(pos, int):
            if pos > -1:
                if isinstance(nbits, int):
                    if nbits > -1:
                        return get_bistring(value | 2 ** (pos % nbits), nbits)
                    else:
                        raise ValueError(
                            '"nbits" was set {}, but it must be positive only'
                            .format(nbits)
                        )
                else:
                    raise TypeError(
                        '"nbits" was set {}, but it must be int only'
                        .format(type(nbits))
                    )
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    '"pos" was set {}, but it must be positive only'
                    .format(pos)
                )
        else:
            raise TypeError(
                '"pos" was set {}, but it must be int only'
                .format(type(pos))
            )
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            '"value" was set {}, but it must be positive only'
            .format(value)
        )
else:
    raise TypeError(
        '"value" was set {}, but it must be int only'
        .format(type(value))
    )
```

Comment: instead of `if else` go with `try` `except`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write it like this

```
import sys

try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
except ValueError:
    print("Could not convert data to an integer.")
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

Answer (score 2):

Invert your logic to simplify your code:

```
def set_bit(value, pos, nbits):
    """
    Set bit at position.

    Keyword Arguments
        value (int)
            Bitstring value.
        pos (int)
            Position to set bit.
        nbits (int)
            Number of bits.
    """
    if not isinstance(value, int):
        raise TypeError('"value" was set {}, but it must be int only'.format(type(value)))
    if value < 0:
        raise ValueError('"value" was set {}, but it must be positive only'.format(value))
    if not isinstance(pos, int):
        raise TypeError('"pos" was set {}, but it must be int only'.format(type(pos)))
    # and so on...

    # once you finish all your checks, then do what you planned to do
```

Since `raise` will automatically cancel the execution of the rest of the function, any code that comes after a conditional raise can assume that the condition didn't apply, so you don't need `else` statements.

Comment: But didn't try-catch statements be more plausive when handling erros? Seems that if-else statements is not the "best" option for this.

Comment: @ÁtilaDiasdaGamaeSilva despite the word 'handle' in the title, the question as written is about raising exceptions, not catching them.